# Check if an OS X user is an administrator?

Tags: macos, user-account

In a script, how can I check if user "Bill" is a member of the admin group (group 80)?

I plan to use this in a script to check if he is and if he is not, make him an admin user.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Another way:

```
if groups username | grep -q -w admin; 
then 
    echo "Is admin"; 
else 
    echo "Not admin"; 
fi
```

- `groups username` will show all username groups.
- `grep -q -w admin` will search (without output `-q`) for word admin in the list of username groups.

As suggest by [David Koontz](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/90735/david-koontz), `groups` has been obsoleted by `id` utility. So, the `if` sentence should looks like the following to do the same:

```
if id -Gn username | grep -q -w admin;
```

Comment: This will also detect people in the "badminton" group, or any other group with admin in the name.

Comment: @Kent, you are right. I update my answer. Using `grep -w` you won't have this problem, as the command select only those lines containing matches that form whole words.

Comment: This isn't "Another way", this is the right one :).
The simplest one, with the standard Unix return code is `isadmin() { groups $1 | grep -q -w admin ; }`.

Comment: Here is "another one": `isadmin() { id -G $1 | grep -q -w 80 ; }`

Comment: man groups - "The groups utility has been obsoleted by the id(1) utility".

Answer (score 8):

See the man page for id.

```
id -G user
```

will output a space delimited list of groups for a particular user. You'd have to detect 80 in the output list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple script to check if the user is in the admin group and if not adds him:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "This script will add a non-admin user to the admin group"
echo "Please enter username"
read username
if groups $username | grep -q -w admin; 
    then 
        echo "User '$username' already is in the admin group"; 
    else 
        dscl . -append /Groups/admin GroupMembership $username;
    echo "User '$username' has been added to the admin group!"; 
    echo "Please restart your Mac to apply the changes."; 
fi
```

Save the script somewhere and make it executable by opening Terminal and entering:

```
chmod 755 /path/to/script
```

Run the script with `sudo /path/to/script`.

Since the default Mac admin of a server OS is a member of several admin groups (e.g. _lpadmin, access_bpf, _appserveradm etc) you might add them as well in the script.

Example:

add the following line to the script to add the user to the 'App Server Admins' group

```
 dscl . -append /Groups/_appserveradm GroupMembership $username;
```

To improve the script you might also add a condition to check if the entered user does exist at all.

Answer (score 0):

**Way 1:**

```
<hostname>:~ zgong$ sudo shutdown
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
zgong is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

**Way 2:**

```
if groups <username> | grep -q -w admin; 
then 
echo "Is admin"; 
else 
echo "Not admin"; 
fi
```

For example:

```
<hostname>:~ zgong$ if groups zgong | grep -q -w admin;
> then
> echo "Is admin";
> else
> echo "Not admin";
> fi
Not admin
```

This is the version easy to copy and paste, just replace zgong with your username.

```
zgong@WM-JFWN6P2F3D ~ % if groups zgong | grep -q -w admin;
then
echo "Is admin";
else
echo "Not admin";
fi
Not admin
```

Reference:
https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/help/script-to-check-if-a-user-is-an-administrator-on-mac/

**Way 3:**
Like mentioned:

```
if id -Gn <username> | grep -q -w admin;
then 
echo "Is admin"; 
else 
echo "Not admin"; 
fi
```

For example:

```
<hostname>:~ zgong$ if id -Gn zgong | grep -q -w admin;
> then
> echo "Is admin";
> else
> echo "Not admin";
> fi
Not admin
```

**Way 4:**

```
dscl . -read /Groups/admin GroupMembership
```

For exmaple:

```
<hostname>:~ zgong$ dscl . -read /Groups/admin GroupMembership


GroupMembership: root _canary littlemac _mbsetupuser
```

Comment: On all my Macs, my main user is a non-admin account but still listed in `/etc/sudoers`, so the first way doesn't work in all cases.

Comment: @nohillside thanks for your info. It will help others :D